# Cross platform create reports from text files

Tags: gratis, cross-platform, charts, reporting

I use GraphViz for a lot of things, but it won't work for what I have in mind. I am looking for something similar for report generation.

I want a tool which takes text files - I don't care which format, probably some command language of its own - and generates graphical files.

**Must have**
- gratis
- takes its input form a text file
- histograms
- PNG, JPG

**Nice to have**
 - I have a strong preference for cross-platform, but might be able to live with a Windows only solution if there is nothing cross platform or if the Windows solution is far superior in features
 - pie charts
 - numerical grids/tables
 - other chart types
 - other fancy reporting stuff(?)
 - lots of options, such as colo(u)rs, titles, labels, etc
 - SVG
 - PDF
 - wide user community, with good support, examples and documentation
 - well established, stable & well tested
 - anythin else that you can think of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of [Python](http://www.python.org) graph drawing libraries that allow you to very quickly generate graphs and either display or save them.  A good starting point is [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/). N.B. For ease of installation on Windows you might like to take a look at [PythonXY](http://python-xy.github.io/downloads.html) which includes both Python, Pandas and Matplotlib, *plus a lot more.*

- gratis - **Yes & Open Source**
- takes its input form a text file - **Yes** *The graph drawing instructions are python which is a text file and the data can be almost any format or source.*
- Interactive Use - **Yes**
- histograms - **Yes**
- PNG, JPG - **PNG definitely**, *JPG if you have PIL or Pillow installed*
- pie charts - **Yes and polar**

[image] [image][image]

- numerical grids/tables - **Yes**
- other chart types - **100s**
- other fancy reporting stuff - **Lots** Especially if you throw **[pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)** into the mix!

  [image]
- lots of options, such as colo(u)rs, titles, labels, etc - **Yes**
- SVG - *Back end dependent*
- PDF - **Yes**
- Cross platform - **Yes - Very**
- wide user community, with good support, examples and documentation - **Very**
- well established, stable & well tested - **Yes** It has been in use by 1000s of people and development since 2002 at least. At this moment [SO reports](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/matplotlib/info) 14,934 questions with the matplotlib tag. There are several books on it's use.

  - There are several matplotlib add-on toolkits, including a choice of two projection and mapping toolkits basemap and cartopy, 3d plotting with mplot3d, axes and axis helpers in axes_grid and more.
    [image]

3D Plot Example:

```
>>> from matplotlib import cm
>>> from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import numpy as np
>>> fig = plt.figure()
>>> ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
>>> X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
>>> Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
>>> X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
>>> R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
>>> Z = np.sin(R)
>>> surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
>>> plt.show()
```

[image]

### See Also Jupyter

If you are producing reports that embed charts I would strongly recommend taking a look at [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) & [iPython](http://ipython.org/) [notebooks](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). This free & open source tool chain will give you a browser based interface to generate your reports including:

- a number of graphing and plotting libraries
- Markdown cells
- MathJax for formulas
- Live data from the web
- Code Cells in Python and a number of other languages such as R, Julia, Haskell & 30+ other languages with the code being executable and the results included of the last run in your report.
- Embed Graphic & Videos from files or online sources
- Save as an iPython Notebook (Text/JSON format),
- Export to python, HTML, MarkDown, Restructured Text reST or PDF.
- Online trial [here](https://try.jupyter.org/) but usually you run a local server, (often on the same machine).

So you can include page layout, introductory text, data, examples, processing results, plots, images, the lot and produce a final output, to pdf, web or both, that looks really professional.

[image]

Comment: Steve, this seems perfect, but I will leave this open to see if it attracts any more answers (which might,, for instance, benefit non-Python guys (maybe C/C++, etc); me? I love Python ).  I would also like to point out to others that this is an excellent example of how to answer. You have obviously spend quite some time to provide a detailed answer which addresses each of my points and the inclusion of an example means that I don'e even have to visit the linked site in order judge whether the too is for for me or not. Thanks!

Comment: @Mawg - Thank-you for the nice words I have expanded slightly to include Jupyter which would allow full report generation and also supports other languages.

Answer (score 1):

[Gnuplot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnuplot) Probably deserves a mention here.

It is and old school command line application dating back to the early days of computer graphics, that used to be pretty widely used but have faded a bit from the limelight with the emergence of IPython.